# MSYS2 bash falls when substitution with pipe inside the loop

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, msys2

The next command I'm trying to execute in MSYS2 x64 and Cygwin64 bash, in the console and as /bin/sh script.

```
for a in 0; do
    echo b=$(echo "c-d" | tr - _)
done
```

Get the output: b=
When the expected: b=c_d

And sh.exe.stackdump file with STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW exception.
This occurs only within a loop, with substitution and with a pipe, with any operation on the line: tr, grep, sed. Bash version 4.4.12 (the last to date).

It is an altered part of the ffmpeg configure script, parse options, which was previously run with no errors in the same Cygwin build.

The original script is

```
for opt do
    case "$opt" in
        #...
        --enable-?*|--disable-?*)
            eval $(echo "$opt" | sed 's/--/action=/;s/-/ option=/;s/-/_/g')
            #...
        ;;
        #...
     esac
done
```

Is there a way to fix this with bash options?

Comment: You say you're running this as a `/bin/sh` script? Did you try as `/bin/bash` script? [Shebang `#!/bin/bash`]

Comment: Yes, I get the same exception

Comment: Is it possible for you to give the 'original part' of the ffmpeg script as well as the 'altered part'? Or what was there before it worked well and what you altered to get this?

Comment: The consist of other packages has changed.

Comment: Updated Windows 10?

Comment: I installed Cygwin, I have windows 10, but I can't replicate this issue! A suggestion maybe, if you have already upgraded to Win10, try [Bash for Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/), it's much much better than cygwin.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in MSYS2 (MINGW64 shell); I always get the expected output as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/5dc9a88ab5df0ca34d34c01d730480f5).  Could you give more details about your environment and exactly how you ran the script?  Did you run `pacman -Syuu` twice to update all MSYS2 packages?

Comment: I have MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit environment (unchanged), the latest packages and the bash version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys). I run code as a shell script and terminal in one line `for a in 0; do echo b=$(echo "c-d" | tr - _); done`. I also installed early versions of bash from [here](http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/).

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem.  I ran the exact command from your latest comment in my shell and I got `b=c_d`.

Comment: Thanks, I think some program in my system conflicts with bash, but it was solved using MSYS2 x32.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe - is taken as an option try -- to specify the end of options:

```
tr -- - _
```

Comment: This is just an example.